# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null in angularjs for google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am using [Google Search Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) to implement Google maps on my website. I have added all the JavaScript in the header. However instead of adding below code to  I have added it in the template which is loaded in Ng-view:

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

When I add the above code in the index.html this error does not occur and the map works.
But I need it to load in the ng-view only. How can I do this?
Also as stated in the question, this is using angularjs structure and language.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If This is an angular app then you should consider using this:
[Angular Google Maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/)